# How to eliminate warning about ambiguity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, warnings, compiler-warnings, office-interop

I have this warning:

> Warning   3   Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application.Quit(ref object, ref object, ref object)' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.Quit'. Using method group.

on my line

```
wordApplication.Quit();
```

I have tried replacing it with:

```
wordApplication.Quit(false); // don't save changes
```

and

```
wordApplication.Quit(false, null, null); // no save, no format
```

but it keeps giving me this warning. It's not a huge problem because the code compiles perfectly and functions as expected, but I'd like to get rid of the warnings. What can I do?

Comment: @HansPassant `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application`

Comment: +1 for persistent relevance. This still comes up after updates to the latest VS for me, in Nov 2013. Only 12 other people had this problem and found this entry? In 2 years? Come on folks, vote stuff up.

Comment: Still relevant for VS2013. +1

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Explicitly cast the reference to the type `_Application`:

```
((_Application)wordApplication).Quit();
```

Comment: There is still the same ambiguity when I do this.

Comment: Did you include the underscore at the beginning of "_Application"?  I would expect that to happen if you left it off, since the "Application" interface inherits from both "_Application" and "ApplicationEvents4_Event".  I'll look into it in some more detail tomorrow.

Comment: Weird. When I originally tried your suggestion, VS put a red underline under `_Application` and said it had no idea what it was. When I typed it again just now, so I could give you the exact error details, it worked fine. Now that it's accepted the cast, it all works fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can also declare your wordApplication variable to be of type _Application.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it tells me the type or namespace '_Application' could not be found.

Comment: Oops, I'm aliasing the namespace since I use both Word and Excel in the same program. So in my case the cast needs to be to Word._Application.

Comment: @Shavais good catch.  This would be easy to overlook when using more than one office library.

Comment: Same applies for the document too, just for the further information. 
  
     ((_Document)WordDoc).Close(true);
     ((_Application)WordApp).Quit();

Answer (score 0):

It's saying there are two quit methods in the included namespace you can if you like change quit to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application.Quit` to remove the message or (haven't personally tried this) use a `using` statement.

Comment: No, it's not! It's saying there is a `Quit()` method and a `Quit` non-method. The non-method is an event. Also, you can't use a `using` in this case as it's only for namespaces and `IDisoposable`s.

Comment: sorry perhaps `two methods` was phrased poorly I mean to say there are two 'things' named quit in the namespace and it does not know how to tell them apart so it is going to guess.

Comment: I know what it's saying. What I don't know is how to remove the ambiguity :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
   object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
   ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)wordApp).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
               wordApp = null;
               GC.Collect();
               GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to define the type of the parameters to Quit.  I use the following, which seems to work.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...
Application wordApplication = new Application();
...
    object paramMissing = Type.Missing;
    object saveOptionsObject = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
        wordApplication.Quit(ref saveOptionsObject, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing);
        wordApplication = null;
```