# Ambiguity between methods

Tags: c#, .net, methods, ms-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to eliminate warning about ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303969/how-to-eliminate-warning-about-ambiguity)

I'm working with MS Office Word in my application,using the following code:

```
var wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var wordDoc = wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref fileName);

//do it..
```

the call of:

```
wordDoc.Close();
wordApplication.Quit();
```

give an:

> Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application.Quit(
>   ref object, ref object, ref object)' and non-method
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.Quit'. Using method group.

I tried to set requests arguments:

```
object nullObject = Type.Missing;
wordDoc.Close(ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject);
wordApplication.Quit(ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject);
```

but it gives same error. How to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please google your error message first...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303969/how-to-eliminate-warning-about-ambiguity

Comment: `((_Application)wordApplication).Quit();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
((_Application)wordApplication).Quit(ref nullObject,
                                     ref nullObject,
                                     ref nullObject);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Actually, the type is `_Application` fix it and I accept your answer.