# open save as docx then close word

Tags: c#, ms-word

So what I want to do is create a program that selects a map with .doc documents open that up save it as a docx then close word. I got it all but when I try to close Word it gives me an error.

Main code:

```
    public void ConvertAll(string docFilePathOriginal, string docFilePath, string outputDocxFilePath)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(docFilePathOriginal);

        DocFiles = new List<string>();
        //calls the method that fills the list with the documents witht the filter.
        FindWordFilesWithDoc(docFilePathOriginal, ".doc");
        //make a new word each time for max performance
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        foreach (string filename in DocFiles)
        {
            //exclude the .docx files, because the filter also accepts .docx files.
            if (filename.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc"))
            {
                try
                {
                var srcFile = new FileInfo(filename);

                var document = word.Documents.Open(srcFile.FullName);
                string docxFilename = srcFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".docx");

                document.SaveAs2(FileName: docxFilename, FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument);
                }
                finally
                {
                    word.ActiveDocument.Close();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Code that gets the .doc files:

```
void FindWordFilesWithDoc(string SelectedDirection, string filter)
    {
        //get all files with the filter and add them to the list.
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(SelectedDirection))
        {
           foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(SelectedDirection))
           {
               DocFiles.Add(f);
           }
            //FindWordFilesWithDoc(d, filter);
        }
    }
```

The error it gives me:

> Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Close(ref object, ref object, ref object)' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentEvents2_Event.Close'. Using method group.

Comment: why do you do word.ActiveDocument.Close();? cant you just call document.Close(true);? Also you are not destroying your COM object, you should be calling Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Object) on document etc...

Comment: Gives me the same error, also it can't find the reference in the finally part thingy.

Comment: There are some duplicates of this question if you search for the error message btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303969/how-to-eliminate-warning-about-ambiguity

Comment: Oh, Sorry. My bad. Googled it, but couldn't find the error ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is a method Close(), and an event Close.

See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/90fa8541-316e-4fac-9885-7c28ef9653b1/ambiguity-between-methods-using-method-group?forum=csharpgeneral). As the poster there states, you probably want to use the method Close() instead of the event. In this case try to cast `word.ActiveDocument` to `_Document`, and call Close() on that.

Edit:
You can also set the type to `_Application`, instead of `Application`:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

(note that I'm unable to test this at the moment, I don't have office installed on my current machine)

Comment: Sorry, this word stuff is new for me. Can you type the code out ? ;$.

Comment: I've added an additional solution which is somewhat neater (though untested unfortunately).

Comment: I'm taking a break now, I've struggled with this error for about 2 hours now. I'll get back to you later. but thanks though !:)

Comment: Well it works now! But now it throws the following error:

comexception was unhandled

at the code:

var document = word.Documents.Open(srcFile.FullName);