# Print a docx file with printer dialog using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, printing, docx

I have a docx document, which I want to print from code behind in C#.
I had gone through forums and few say, its not possible, i will have to use JavaScript.
How to specify file in JavaScript, print code?
So far I have done in code behind direct print.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = file;
process.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
process.Start();
//process.Kill();
```

Comment: Semi-unrelated to your question, but you shouldn't kill your process immediately after starting it - then surely nothing will happen. Just start the process, and let it do its job. Only kill the process if you absolutely need to.

Comment: ok, but I am also looking for the printer dialog to appear, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a few of these posted here. This one would best suite I think.

[Printing using Word Interop with Print Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878302/printing-using-word-interop-with-print-dialog)

The basic premise is that you need to open the file in code using Microsoft.Office.Interop libraries, then perform your print. You can't just point the print process at a file.

Edit: [PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx) class should help you with dialog.

Comment: i am trying to print a document using javascript, the problem is i dont want to show print dialog, but manually pass number of copies and specify pages. can someone help me out? it would be great if i could get my hands on some javascript snippet.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible. Javascript's window.print doesn't allow any parameters and the browser will be the one handling the print process. It's up the user's browser preferences.

Answer (score -1):

See [this blog post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/13946/print-any-document-file-using-a-C-Sharp-code-without-opening-docu.aspx). Basically:

```
// Using below code we can print any document
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(txtFileName.Text.Trim());
info.Verb = "Print";
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(info);
```